Run a Vite server within configureServer of another Vite server
Wondering if it's possible to run a Vite server within another.
I'm trying to create a plugin that serves assets of another library in a monorepo. I can't seem to get both running at the same time.
import { createServer } from 'vite';

const CONFIG_FILE = "...";

export default function viteMyServer() {
  return {
    name: 'vite-plugin-my-server',
    async configureServer(server) {
      const viteService = await createServer({
        configFile: CONFIG_FILE,
        appType: "custom",
        server: {
          middlewareMode: true,
        },
      });

      server.middlewares.use(viteService.middlewares.handle);
    }
  }
}


Why do you want to do this instead of running two servers with a proxy?
